# Karate - how to send body as form data

Tags: karate, form-data

These are my fields in form-data

```
uploaded_by = x@y.com
status = true
file = Excel File to be uploaded
```

Here is the code I tried

```
    Given url baseUrl + uploadTemplate
    And multipart field uploaded_by = <user>
    And multipart field status = <status>
    And multipart field file = read('Template.xlsx')
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And match $.result == <result>

Examples: 
| user      | status | result  |
| 'x@y.com' | true   | INITIAL |
```

Excel File is present in the same location where feature file is there , I am getting 500 error , But working well from POSTMAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with following code

```
    Given url baseUrl + uploadTemplate
    And multipart field uploaded_by = <user>
    And multipart field status = <status>
    And multipart field file = { read: 'Template.xlsx', filename: 'Template.xlsx', contentType: 'multipart/form-data' }
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And match $.result == <result>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `form field` instead of `multipart field`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#form-field

Comment: Now I am getting 415 media unsupported error , after changing it to form field.  Working fine from postman and I have checked there is not any header data

Comment: ```timestamp":1568963519875,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'```